# Sync Google Sheets with Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-sheets, synchronization

Can you help me sync data between Google SpreadSheets and Google Maps?  Once I import data into google maps, it shows nice pins of each location. But, the spreadsheet does not sync and I have to keep importing.

I want to have a spreadsheet that has two columns (Location and Number of Racks) and as it is updated, it automatically updates the map.  I made the map through google maps with the import google spreadsheet feature.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can get the sync code [here](https://gist.github.com/chrislkeller/4026676). Once synced, you can put the data on the google map

Comment: He needs to keep synced the map with the data of the spreadsheet. I'm looking for the same..